# Creating a class Encoder which extends keras.Model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, encoder

I am implementing an Encoder.

There are two versions: version 1 does not use OOP while version 2 does, but isn't working.

**1. Version 1, working:**

```
def sample(z_mean, z_log_var, distribution=tf.random.normal):
    batch = tf.shape(z_mean)[0]
    dim = tf.shape(z_mean)[1]
    epsilon = distribution(shape=(batch, dim))
    stddev = tf.exp(0.5 * z_log_var)
    return z_mean + stddev * epsilon

encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(encoder_inputs)
x = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(units=16, activation="relu")(x)
z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")(x)
z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")(x)
z = sample(z_mean, z_log_var)
encoder = keras.Model(encoder_inputs, [z_mean, z_log_var, z], name="encoder")
encoder.summary()
```

whose output is:

```
Model: "encoder"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
==================================================================================================
 input_1 (InputLayer)        [(None, 32, 32, 3)]          0         []                            
                                                                                                  
 conv2d (Conv2D)             (None, 16, 16, 32)           896       ['input_1[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_1 (Conv2D)           (None, 8, 8, 64)             18496     ['conv2d[0][0]']              
                                                                                                  
 flatten (Flatten)           (None, 4096)                 0         ['conv2d_1[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 dense (Dense)               (None, 16)                   65552     ['flatten[0][0]']             
                                                                                                  
 z_mean (Dense)              (None, 2)                    34        ['dense[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 z_log_var (Dense)           (None, 2)                    34        ['dense[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 tf.compat.v1.shape (TFOpLa  (2,)                         0         ['z_mean[0][0]']              
 mbda)                                                                                            
                                                                                                  
 tf.compat.v1.shape_1 (TFOp  (2,)                         0         ['z_mean[0][0]']              
 Lambda)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 tf.math.multiply (TFOpLamb  (None, 2)                    0         ['z_log_var[0][0]']           
 da)                                                                                              
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.getitem (  ()                           0         ['tf.compat.v1.shape[0][0]']  
 SlicingOpLambda)                                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.getitem_1  ()                           0         ['tf.compat.v1.shape_1[0][0]']
  (SlicingOpLambda)                                                                               
                                                                                                  
 tf.math.exp (TFOpLambda)    (None, 2)                    0         ['tf.math.multiply[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 tf.random.normal (TFOpLamb  (None, 2)                    0         ['tf.__operators__.getitem[0][
 da)                                                                0]',                          
                                                                     'tf.__operators__.getitem_1[0
                                                                    ][0]']                        
                                                                                                  
 tf.math.multiply_1 (TFOpLa  (None, 2)                    0         ['tf.math.exp[0][0]',         
 mbda)                                                               'tf.random.normal[0][0]']    
                                                                                                  
 tf.__operators__.add (TFOp  (None, 2)                    0         ['z_mean[0][0]',              
 Lambda)                                                             'tf.math.multiply_1[0][0]']  
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 85012 (332.08 KB)
Trainable params: 85012 (332.08 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
```

Now, if I Invoke `predict` method on train data, as follows:

```
(x_train, y_train), _ = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1).astype("float32") / 255
encoder.predict(x_train)
```

This correctly works:

```
1563/1563 [==============================] - 2s 1ms/step

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**2. Version 2, not working:**

In order to make version 1 cleaner and more maintainable, I aimed to extract a class for the logic of the encoder as follows:

```
class Encoder(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.conv1 = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")
        self.conv2 = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=3, activation="relu", strides=2, padding="same")
        self.flatten = layers.Flatten()
        self.dense1 = layers.Dense(units=16, activation="relu")
        self.z_mean = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_mean")
        self.z_log_var = layers.Dense(latent_dim, name="z_log_var")
        self.sampling = sample

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        x = self.conv1(inputs)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.flatten(x)
        x = self.dense1(x)
        z_mean = self.z_mean(x)
        z_log_var = self.z_log_var(x)
        z = self.sampling(z_mean, z_log_var)
        return z_mean, z_log_var, z
```

and the main is:

```
encoder_inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
encoder = Encoder(latent_dim)
z_mean, z_log_var, z = encoder(encoder_inputs)
encoder.summary()
```

whose output is:

```
Model: "encoder"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 conv2d_2 (Conv2D)           multiple                  896       
                                                                 
 conv2d_3 (Conv2D)           multiple                  18496     
                                                                 
 flatten_1 (Flatten)         multiple                  0         
                                                                 
 dense_1 (Dense)             multiple                  65552     
                                                                 
 z_mean (Dense)              multiple                  34        
                                                                 
 z_log_var (Dense)           multiple                  34        
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 85012 (332.08 KB)
Trainable params: 85012 (332.08 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
```

Now, if I invoke:

```
(x_train, y_train), _ = keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
x_train = np.expand_dims(x_train, -1).astype("float32") / 255
encoder.predict(x_train)
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/vae.py", line 226, in <module>
    encoder.predict(x_train)
  File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/var/folders/gh/hgbtzhqd5xv5rwqj0snp33qm0000gn/T/__autograph_generated_fileapcgkjiq.py", line 15, in tf__predict_function
    retval_ = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(step_function), (ag__.ld(self), ag__.ld(iterator)), None, fscope)
    ^^^^^
  File "/var/folders/gh/hgbtzhqd5xv5rwqj0snp33qm0000gn/T/__autograph_generated_file94o9x87j.py", line 10, in tf__call
    x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).conv1, (ag__.ld(inputs),), None, fscope)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: in user code:

    File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2341, in predict_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2327, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2315, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.predict_step(data)
    File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/training.py", line 2283, in predict_step
        return self(x, training=False)
    File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
        raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    File "/var/folders/gh/hgbtzhqd5xv5rwqj0snp33qm0000gn/T/__autograph_generated_file94o9x87j.py", line 10, in tf__call
        x = ag__.converted_call(ag__.ld(self).conv1, (ag__.ld(inputs),), None, fscope)

    ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer 'encoder' (type Encoder).
    
    in user code:
    
        File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/vae.py", line 183, in call  *
            x = self.conv1(inputs)
        File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler  **
            raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
        File "/Users/alex/PycharmProjects/VAE-EEG-XAI/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/keras/src/engine/input_spec.py", line 280, in assert_input_compatibility
            raise ValueError(
    
        ValueError: Input 0 of layer "conv2d_2" is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 3, but received input with shape (None, 32, 32, 3, 1)
    
    
    Call arguments received by layer 'encoder' (type Encoder):
      • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 32, 32, 3, 1), dtype=float32)
      • training=False
      • mask=None


Process finished with exit code 1
```

How should I fix version 2?